# How to upload single image multipletimes(morethan 100 times)?

Tags: image, image-processing, file-upload, for-loop, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I am working on MVC4. I have uploaded a single image file, it is saved in the destination folder, but now I need a loop so that image the is saved more than 100 times.

Here is my code,

This is my controller:

```
     [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Uploading(ImageModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {     
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~");
                string imagesPath = serverPath + "Content\\Images\\";
                string thumsise = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Thumb" + fileName);

                ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumsise, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 80, true);

            }
            return View("Upload",model);
        }
```

and this is my index page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     {
         <input type="file" name="ImageUploaded" id="btnUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"  />
     <button type="submit"  id="Upload">Upload</button>
         <br />
}
```

Could you please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want to save the same image a 100 times?

Comment: actually need to find the time of loop takes time

Comment: time of 1 or 100 loops?  still don't see why you'd need a 100

Comment: Thanks mr.dove you are spending time for me i got the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing a [`for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploading(ImageModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {     
        string imagesPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images");
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
        {
            string thumsise = Path.Combine(
                imagesPath, 
                string.Format("Thumb{0}_{1}", fileName, i)
            );
            ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumsise, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 80, true);
        }
        return View("Upload",model);
    }
}
```

This will create 100 images in the `~/Content/Images` folder by prefixing the Guid with `Thumb` and by suffixing it with the index of the loop.

Comment: Thanks mr.Darin Dimitrov its woking for me nice coding thank you very much and thanks for reply for me